# "WriteLinesToFile" task was not given a value for the required parameter "File"

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, blazor, blazor-webassembly

Error   MSB4044 The "WriteLinesToFile" task was not given a value for the required parameter "File".    BlazorTutorial.Client   C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\5.0.400\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.BlazorWebAssembly\targets\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.BlazorWebAssembly.ServiceWorkerAssetsManifest.targets

```
 // !---Line that gives error
 <WriteLinesToFile
      File="%(_ServiceWorkerIntermediateFile.Identity)"
      Lines="/* Manifest version: $(_ServiceWorkerAssetsManifestVersion) */"
      Condition="'$(_ServiceWorkerAssetsManifestVersion)' != ''" />
```

I don't how to resolve this or don't know what other information have to share here. I looked over internet but couldn't find any information about this error.

> Things i tried :

- I tried update sdk version 5.0.3 to 5.0.4 but not worked.
- Meaningless but updated visual studio.
- I reverted project to working version from git still getting same error.
- I tried open new project and there was no error.

**Edit 1:**

- (@Nicola Biada thank you) Cleared project > exited visual studio > deleted bin and obj folders > opened project > rebuilded project > same error accurred

**Solved but don't know why:***

```
// from server's program.cs
public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
       Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
           .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
           {       
                webBuilder.UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()); // Deleted this line
                webBuilder.UseWebRoot("wwwroot"); // And this
                webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
           });
```

After that, deleted wwwroot folder at server side and magic become real error gone for good.

Comment: Try to: 1. clean the project, 2. exit VS, 3. delete bin folder, 4. delete obj folder, 5. open the project and rebuild

Comment: Is that `%` a typo? How does a `@` work?

Comment: @Henk Holterman I don't know when getting error redirects me to sdk's Microsoft.NET.Sdk.BlazorWebAssembly.ServiceWorkerAssetsManifest.targets file

Comment: Yes, I thought for a moment this was from your own code. But it's a Build target.

Answer (score 6):

For me, this part of the Blazor.csproj got lost.

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <ServiceWorker Include="wwwroot\service-worker.js" PublishedContent="wwwroot\service-worker.published.js" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

Comment: This answer solve my error, It seems some how this line deleted from my csproj

Comment: Same here: I know I added this line, so Visual Studio must have deleted it for some reason, but adding it back fixed the issue.